# Перестал работать плагин в jQuery 1.9?

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин

Плагин `jQuery` `DropKick` `1.0.0`, ошибки консоли:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropkick'
```

Исправить их еще как-то можно (судя по issues на github'e), но работать он все равно не будет, что можно сделать?

п.с. этот плагин делает выпадающие списки более-менее красивее.

Тест на jsfiddle: [dropkick](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/h5N9c/) ( по умолчанию подключена 1.9 версия (не рабочая), попробуйте 1.8 и получите красивый список ).

Оф.страница: http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

снижать версию `jQuery` на сайте не хочется. Сам я уже пробовал и `live` на `on` изменить  везде и `$.browser` на `ie` переделать, но это ничего не дало.

Вот [исходник](http://codepaste.ru/13422/) моих правок.

`Обновил` [исходник с поправками](http://codepaste.ru/13425/) (визуально плагин сработал, функционально -нет.)

Comment: Попробуйте переделать исходники под ИЕ т.е. убрать msie, а также поправить bind и live на on и посмотреть что вам выдаст js консоль.

Comment: так я это и сделал, куда можно скрипт выложить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что Вам нужно изменить в коде плагина:

1) Поменять:

// Help prevent flashes of unstyled content
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) < 7) {
    ie6 = true;
  } else {
    document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className + ' dk_fouc';
  }

на

document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className + ' dk_fouc';

2) В строке 343 поменять метод live на on
3) В строке 358 поменять  
       $('.dk_options a').live(($.browser.msie ? 'mousedown' : 'click'), function (e) {
на 
    $('.dk_options a').on('click', function (e) {

Comment: я добавил исходник правок. Визуально выпадающий список стал лучше, но функционал отсутствует.

Comment: Действительно не работает, потому что я Вам чушь написал. Если коротко, то Вам нужно переписать метод .live() на метод .on(), однако это не просто названия поменять. По ссылке ниже можно почитать, как это сделать:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161691/replacing-jquery-live-with-jquery-on-doesnt-work

Comment: я чувствую что не один такой плагин прийдется переделывать, учитывая 2-й `jQuery`.

Comment: уберу пока его вообще с сайта. Может с `UI` что-нть возьму.

Comment: Лучше использовать другой плагин для select'ов. Этот два года уже не обновляют.

Comment: С jquery 1.9 много плагинов работать корректно не будут. Либо ждать обновлений, либо менять, ну или же руками править (но легче обновить на другой).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ 
Это должно помочь.
даже если вот тут http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/h5N9c/ Сбоку выбрать "migrate" все заработает

Answer (score 0):

$.browser был удален из jQuery начиная с версии 1.9. Теперь это доступно отдельно как плагин - https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin